# Return a generic closure type based on the input parameters

Tags: ios, swift, api, generics, struct

I have my struct that is called APIManager. This struct has the job to call some APIs and return their values. This is how it is organized :

```
struct APIManager {

  public static func checkEmail(_ email: String, success: @escaping (_ status: String) -> Void, failure: @escaping FailureBlock) {

     Alamofire
            .request(Router.LoginProcess.checkEmail(email: email))
            .validate()
            .responseJSON { (response: DataResponse<Any> ) in

                switch response.result {
                case .success(_):
                    if let value = response.result.value {
                        let json = JSON(value)
                        let userStatus = User.Status(rawValue: json["status"].intValue)

                        success(userStatus ?? User.Status.unknown)
                    }
                    break

                case .failure(let error):
                    failure()
                    break
                }
        }

  }



  public static func block(
      reason: User.BlockReason,
      success: @escaping () -> Void,
      failure: @escaping FailureBlock) {

      Alamofire
          .request(Router.LoginProcess.block(reason: reason))
          .validate()
          .responseJSON { (response: DataResponse<Any> ) in

              switch response.result {
              case .success(_):
                  success()
                  break

              case .failure(_):
                  failure()
                  break
              }
      }
  }

}
```

As you can see, much of the code could be reused creating a method called `call(_ api: API.Type)`, but the problem would be in the `success` block, because it is different on each method. How can I achieve a result like the following?

```
public static func call(_ api: API.Type, success: GenericSuccessBlock, failure: FailureBlock) {
  ...
}
```

Where the `GenericSuccessBlock` will be typed using a block declared as `typealias` based on the `api` parameter that will be an `enum`.

Comment: I wrote something like this: https://github.com/Brandon-T/Blocky  It allows you to "store" ANY kind of block and call it later or store it with its parameters and call it later. So if your function accepted a `BlockFunction` or a `Function`, you could do it.

Comment: Maybe declaring `success` as type `{ Any -> Any }`. Something like that might work.

Comment: @Brandon your code is interesting, thanks for sharing it!